# CSS puzzle: move last two item of the navigation to the right

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-float

I have a horizontal navigation, and I want the last two item to be pushed to the right side of the container.

With only one item, I could simply float the last item of the navigation. But I want to apply this to two elements - and I have the constraint that their order has to be the same in HTML and for the viewer.

I tried the following, but this broke my javascript code which relies on

```
$('... a').parent().next().doSomething(...)
```

The code

```
<ul class="main main-nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="#projekte" class="first">Projekte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#aktuell">Aktuell</a></li> 
    <div class="push-right"> 
        <li><a href="#about">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
        <li><a href="#kurse">Kurse</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Is there some obvious solution I don't see?
Any other shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't place a `div` inside of a `ul`:

```
<ul class="main main-nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="#projekte" class="first">Projekte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#aktuell">Aktuell</a></li>

    <li class="push-right"><a href="#about">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li> 
    <li class="push-right"><a href="#kurse">Kurse</a></li>
    <!-- Or Flip them to maintain order --> 
    <li class="push-right"><a href="#kurse">Kurse</a></li>
    <li class="push-right"><a href="#about">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.push-right{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the validation tip!

Comment: "float: right" does not work because it changes the order - as I mentioned I need the order of the li's to be the same both in HTML and on screen.

Comment: There's no way to keep them the same in html and on the page without an enclosing tag like you were trying to do, but by doing that, you will have to adjust your javascript.